# Can I make a dive attack with a bow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, flight

Improved draconic wings states that:

> You can make a dive attack. A dive attack works like a charge(...). You can make a dive attack only when wielding a piercing weapon.

Since the bow deals piercing damage, could I make a dive attack with it?

The "works like a charge" part got me confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Charging](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge) only permits a (single) melee attack, so you can't make a ranged attack as part of a dive attack:

> After moving, you may make a single melee attack.

That only makes sense, anyway. The point of a dive attack, like in a charge, is to add the impact of your body's own momentum to the attack, which doesn't work for a missile that impacts by itself.

Comment: (well, actually, it does work in RL.  But that's besides the point)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Sort of. It's not the same mechanism, since you're not forcing the target flesh to absorb all or a large fraction of your pesonal body's momentum, you're using your relative speeds to impart a tiny bit more force to the projectile. Same idea, vastly different physics.

Comment: That is absolutely true.  I upvoted, I'm just not good at letting things go ^^;

Answer (score 0):

With a bow, no. Only a melee piercing weapon works because the rules for a charge specify that a melee weapon must be used. Funnily, there are two melee weapons that **deliver a crossbow bolt**: the Spear Spikard and War Spikard (Magic of Eberron pp137~138).

> A spear spikard resembles a thicker-than-normal shortspear. [truncated] A spear spikard is actually a hollow weapon capable of delivering a bolt as part of a melee strike.
>
> (Magic of Eberron p137)
>
> A war spikard is similar in principle to the spear spikard, but its crossbow mechanism is melded smoothly into a weapon that resembles an oversized warhammer.
>
> (Magic of Eberron p138)